# Jar Files in Oracle ADF application

Tags: web, jar, oracle-adf

Is this a good coding practice of making a jar file of an ADF application and then placing it in main ADF application. (its like presence of customed developed jar files inside a war file)
I believe that it will cause severe memory issues on server but i can't find requisite link or source which states that it should be avoided.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

We are also using the same practice and same is mentioned in Oracle docs, It increases the reusability of application.
I don't think that it'll cause memory issue but yes there are connection pool issues sometimes.